# Get-ChildItem inside the A Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

I have a question about a script I am writing.  I need a script that can find all folders inside a specific folder (in this case WRA), but I also want to find the sub-folders inside WRA
For example:
\Server01\WRA contains 100 folders
\Server01\WRA\Folder 1
\Server01\WRA\Folder 2
...
...

I want to look inside the "Folder 1" and obtain a report of the folders inside "Folder 1" and locate the folders older than 30 days which can be done with

```
Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))}
```

This is what I have so far

```
$FolderNames = Get-ChildItem "\\Server01\WRA\" -Directory | 
    Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime

$FolderNames
```

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\Server01\WRA\" -Directory |
Get-ChildItem -Directory |
Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT ([datetime]::Now).AddDays(-30) |
Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime
```

#### Edit

```
$directories = Get-ChildItem "\\Server01\WRA\" -Directory
$targetDate = ([datetime]::Now).AddDays(-30)

foreach($parentDir in $directories)
{
    $subFolders = Get-ChildItem $parentDir -Directory |
    Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT $targetDate
    
    if($subFolders)
    {
        "Parent Directory: {0}" -f $parentDir.FullName
    }

    foreach($childDir in $subFolders)
    {
        "Parent SubFolder: {0}" -f $childDir.FullName

        $childDir | Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime | Out-String
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I was looking for, thank you!!!!
Would it be possible to put the parent folder name above the sub-folders?
Example:
Folder 1 (Parent)
... Test 1 (Subfolder)
... Test 2 (Subfolder)
... Test 3 (Subfolder)
Thank you so much!

Comment: My main goal is...
Each folder inside the WRA folder belongs to a person..
I need to send an email to that person with the amount of folder she/he has

Comment: I have created a TXT file which the email of the person who owns that folder, so I can send her/him a report with old the sub-folder under her/his folder in the WRA folder.  I hope it make sense

Comment: @Miguel Yes it is possible but the code will change a bit. I'm not sure if this is what you want. I edited the code.